# Replace the value of a column based on value of multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, replace, conditional-statements

In a DataFrame I need to replace the NUMBER with the ID of the same row where its ID is different from the NUMBER and has CARDINAL equal to SOUTH.

I did not find a solution to compare two columns of the same row with an additional condition.

```
if (df['ID'] != df['NUMBER']) & (df['CARDINAL'] == 'SOUTH') then replace df['NUMBER'] with df['ID']
```

```
ID     NAME       NUMBER    CARDINAL    
---
01    COUNTRY1    01        NORTH   <-- <ID> == <NUMBER>                       --> not change
02    COUNTRY2    12        WEST    <-- <ID> != <NUMBER> & CARDINAL != 'SOUTH' --> not change
03    COUNTRY3    13        SOUTH   <-- <ID> != <NUMBER> & CARDINAL == 'SOUTH' --> change <NUMBER> to <ID>
...
04    COUNTRYX    54        WEST    <-- <ID> != <NUMBER> & CARDINAL != 'SOUTH' --> not change
05    COUNTRYY    55        SOUTH   <-- <ID> != <NUMBER> & CARDINAL == 'SOUTH' --> change <NUMBER> to <ID>
06    COUNTRYZ    06        NORTH   <-- <ID> == <NUMBER>                       --> not change
```

The result should be:

```
ID     NAME       NUMBER    CARDINAL    
---
01    COUNTRY1    01        NORTH       
02    COUNTRY2    12        WEST        
03    COUNTRY3    03        SOUTH       <-- <NUMBER> replaced with <ID>
...
04    COUNTRYX    54        WEST        
05    COUNTRYY    05        SOUTH       <-- <NUMBER> replaced with <ID>
06    COUNTRYZ    06        NORTH
```

I tried:

```
df["NUMBER"] = df.loc[(df["ID"] != df["NUMBER"]) & (df["CARDINAL"] == "SOUTH"), "ID"]
```

and

```
df.loc[(df["ID"] != df["NUMBER"]) & (df["CARDINAL"] == "SOUTH"), "NUMBER"] = df["ID"]
```

none of them worked

Comment: Use `numpy.select`